# Track the LDAP request failures in the domain controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

In our environment we have configured the application servers to connect the domain controllers for LDAP request over the port number 389 and it is working fine for a long time

Recently the application owners reported their application's were not able to connect the domain controllers over LDAP (389), So to fix the issue immediately i have asked to application owners to re point their applications to different domain controller. Please note, Application servers and DC's are in the same subnet, there is no network devices in between.

My question is, In general how to check the LDAP queries sent from the application severs are successfully processed by the Domain controller or it is failed at the DC level ? I cannot use the network monitor or Wireshark in my DC due to some restrictions, Please let me know what is the debug logging mechanism available in the domain controller to identify the successfully processed LDAP request and the failed LDAP request at the DC level ?

What is the recommended approach, If we have multiple domain controllers in the site, rather than pointing the application server to the specific Domain controller, can we point the application servers to contact the common endpoint (Load Balancer), then load balance the LDAP request between the DC's based upon the availability of server and service ?

Comment: the actual literal application error would be useful here. what app stack, and exception information? blocked connections by the firewall should display in the security evebnt logs, and exceptions in the ldap service should display in the application event logs. are the servers relationship with the domain healthy? does removing and readding them have any impact?

Comment: There areliterally tons of resources available about LDAP logging on DC's, just google for it ? If you need to actually monitor the network traffic, you can mirror the port the DC is on.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you for your response, Most of the applications pointed to that specific DC reported the issue. I don't think there is a problem with the application and there is not firewall between the DC and application servers. After that DC is rebooted, the applications were able to connect that DC without any issues. For now, my intention is not to identify the cause for this issue, but in general i need to know the answer for the two questions, Kindly check and share your thoughts specifically for the questions